# Is it possible to use environment variables within solrconfig.xml for dataDir variable?

Tags: solr

We have a situation where we have to maybe create multiple instances of Solr/Tomcat running on different ports on either a single machine or several different machines. Towards doing this I was wondering if it's possible to specify the dataDir variable (within solrconfig.xml) using an environmentvariable for example like so: `<dataDir>${envvar}/path/to/index</dataDir>`.

Comment: Not sure if you can use environment variables, but system properties can be used as explained [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#System_property_substitution).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As i'm working on a similar setup, i needed this too. I don't think it's good practise to use ENV variables for this. You are probably better off using the multicore setup or use a property file in solr.xml.

eg.

```
<core name="core_1" instanceDir="core_1" properties="core1.properties" />
```

and then in your core1.properties:

```
config.datadir=/datadir1
```

and then use that in your solrconfig.xml:

```
<dataDir>${config.datadir}</dataDir>
```

Cheers,

Patrick

Comment: Can it be used in data-config.xml too?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do this, but you need to do jump through a couple hoops to set this up [using system properties passed to the JVM](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#System_property_substitution) when you start it.

Anywhere you want your environment variable to work in your configuration files, put the variable like this:

```
${VAR}
```

Then, when you start your JVM, pass it the variable by doing:

```
java -DVAR=$your-system-variable
```

So, to make this concrete, here's what we do:

```
java -DINSTALL_ROOT=$INSTALL_ROOT -jar -server start.jar
```

And our config has something like:

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms=${INSTALL_ROOT}/Solr/conf/synonyms.txt />
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Go [multi-core](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) .

You can tell Solr to deploy a particular index directory as a core. For example, to deploy a Solr index on `path_to_instance_directory` on  `http://localhost:8983/solr/coreX`, you would do:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=coreX&instanceDir=path_to_instance_directory&config=config_file_name.xml&schema=schem_file_name.xml&dataDir=data
```

You can tell Solr to create, load, swap two running cores, swap a running core with an inactive core etc.

Answer (score 0):

As explained on [wiki.apache.org](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#System_property_substitution), you can use system property substitution in `solrconfig.xml` like below:

```
<dataDir>${data.dir}</dataDir>
```

Then you can specify values in a properties file:

```
#solrcore.properties
data.dir=/data/solrindex
```

---

Another way is to dictate the data directory during Solr runtime in this manner:

```
java -Dsolr.data.dir=/data/dir -jar start.jar
```

and in XML file use the following syntax:

```
<dataDir>${solr.data.dir:./solr/data}</dataDir>
```

---

I think the better method is to define `solr.xml` within your `solr.home`, e.g.:

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
 <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
  <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" dataDir="/var/lib/solr/core0" />
  <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" dataDir="/var/lib/solr/core1" />
 </cores>
</solr>
```

Note: I don't think you can use any external variables here.

---

Finally using JVM system property file (e.g. `solr.xml`) in `conf/Catalina/localhost`, for example:

```
<Context docBase="webapps/solr.war" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/opt/solr/ads_solr" override="true" />
  <Environment name="solr/data/dir" type="java.lang.String" value="/var/lib/solr" override="true" />
</Context>
```

where `solr/home` would work, however `solr/data/dir` [won't work](https://serverfault.com/q/695154/130437) without patching your Solr.

See: [tomcat_solr.xml.erb](https://github.com/activelamp/solr_drupal6/blob/0cdda297e82be73c7f063638b7e12106d17745b0/puppet/modules/solr/templates/tomcat_solr.xml.erb)